# Copy/paste vector linked to a Data validated cell for all validation values

Tags: vba, excel, validation

The values of a vector `Worksheets("sheet1").Range("C2:C1000")` are linked with the value of one cell `Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1")` - which is data validated from a range `Worksheets("List").Range("B1:xxxxx1")`.

I would like to copy and paste the values of the column vector `Worksheets("sheet1").Range("C2:C1000")` for all possible values of  `Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1")` in new columns.
The final result should be a table of the same column "N" times with N = count of data validated values, stored in `Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A2")`.

EDIT : added a sample data at the end for clarity, as per comment's request

```
sub CopyBasedonDataValidation



'The loop will stop when there's no more data validated values in A1
For i = 1 To Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A2").Value



'First I am pasting the data validated values in A1 to change the column vector. 

 Worksheets("List").Range("A1").Offset(0, i).Copy
 Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues


'Then I am pasting the column vector into a new sheet. 

 Worksheets("sheet1").Range("C2:C1000").Copy
 Worksheets("newsheet").Range("A1").Offset(0, i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues


Next i
End Sub
```

The outcome is a table with n columns but with the same values in all the columns. I presume the data validated cell does not change the linked vector in column B with my method. Any thoughts?

---

`Worksheets("sheet1")`

```
 "Loc1"          B1           C1
  N              Obs1         Good
                 Obs2         Good
                 Obs3         Bad
                 Obs4         VGood
                 ...          ...
                 Obs1000      Bad
```

If change A1 to "Loc2" then C column changes

```
 "Loc2"          B1           C1
  N              Obs1         Avge
                 Obs2         Bad
                 Obs3         Avge
                 Obs4         Good
                 ...          ...
                 Obs1000      VBad
```

If A1 becomes "Loc3" then C column changes again ...

```
 "Loc3"          B1           C1
  N              Obs1         VBad
                 Obs2         VBad
                 Obs3         VGood
                 Obs4         Avge
                 ...          ...
                 Obs1000      Good
```

---

Output table :

```
           Loc1      Loc2      Loc3      Loc4      ...      LocN
Obs1       Good      Avge      VBad      Good      ...      VBad
Obs2       Good      Bad       VBad      VGood     ...      Avge
Obs3       Bad       Avge      VGood     Good      ...      VBad
Obs4       VGood     Good      Avge      Avge      ...      VBad 
...        ...       ...       ...       ...       ...      ...
Obs1000    Bad       VBad      Good      Good      ...      VBad
```

Here Column B will change based on the values of `Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1")` (Loc1 to LocN that I can find in `Worksheets("sheet2").Range("B1:xxxxx1")`)

Comment: Can you give two more pictures - the one with the initial data and the second one with the expected data?
Change the data to something meaningless, not to expose your own.

Comment: Added the output table. I have one dynamic column "B" that changes values based on the value of A1 - from Loc1 to LocN. Thanks for the help...

Comment: Thanks for the pictures, but sorry, I still do not get it. So, what would help is really 2 pictures - initial data and expected output data. Furthermore, if you can explain how from the first one your would like to receive the second one - it will be helpful

Comment: My bad, I did not shape the tables well.  Hope it makes more sense with the  `Worksheets("sheet1")` image. Mind that I changed the column vector from B to C

Answer (score 0):

Would this be what you're looking for?

```
Sub CopyBasedonDataValidation()
    Application.EnableEvents = False: Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    On Error GoTo Cleanup
    Dim validCell As Range, targetCol As Range
    With Worksheets.Add
        .Name = "ValidationSheet"
        .Columns("A").Value = Worksheets("sheet1").Columns("B").Value
        Set targetCol = .Columns("B")
    End With

    With Worksheets("sheet1")
        'We fetch the data from the validation list
        For Each validCell In Application.Range(.Range("A2").Validation.Formula1)
            .Range("A1").Value = validCell.Value
            .Calculate
            targetCol.Value = .Columns("C").Value
            targetCol.Cells(1).Value = validCell.Value
            Set targetCol = targetCol.Offset(, 1)
        Next
    End With
Cleanup:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox Err.Description
    Application.EnableEvents = True: Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I had tested it but then you changed the problem and now you need column to copy column "C". :D

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, something like this should help you:

```
sub CopyBasedonDataValidation

    dim lngLastCol  as long 

    'The loop will stop when there's no more data validated values in A1
    'First I am pasting the data validated values in A1 to change the column vector.        
    lngLastCol = lastColumn("sheet1")+1

     Worksheets("List").Columns(i).Copy
     Worksheets("sheet1").Columns(lngLastCol).pastespecial Paste:= xlvalues
End Sub


Function last_column(Optional str_sheet As String, Optional row_to_check As Long = 1) As Long

    Dim shSheet  As Worksheet

    If str_sheet = vbNullString Then
        Set shSheet = ActiveSheet
    Else
        Set shSheet = Worksheets(str_sheet)
    End If

    last_column = shSheet.Cells(row_to_check, shSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End Function
```

The code goes to the Sheet `List` and copies the second column. Then it adds it, after the last column in `Sheet1`.

Answer (score 0):

you could try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyBasedonDataValidation()
    Dim dataRng As Range, validCell As Range, validRng As Range, cell As Range

    With Worksheets("sheet1") '<--| reference "sheet1"
        Set validCell = .Range("A1") '<--| set the range where to change validation values
        Set dataRng = .Range("c2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp)) '<--| set validation cell i.e.: the range where data changes
    End With

    With Worksheets("sheet2")  '<--| reference "sheet2"
        Set validRng = .Range("B1", .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) '<--| set the range with not blank validation values
    End With

    With Worksheets("newsheet") '<--| reference "newsheet"
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual '<--| prevent calculation before writing to referenced sheet
        .Range("A2").Resize(dataRng.Rows.Count).Value = dataRng.Offset(, -1).Value '<--| write rows "headers"
        For Each cell In validRng '<--| loop through validation range
            Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic '<--| restore calculation
            validCell.Value = cell.Value '<--| change validation cell to current validation value
            Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual '<--| prevent calculation before writing to referenced sheet
            With .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1) '<-- reference currently "free" column
                .Value = cell.Value '<--| write current validation value
                .Offset(1).Resize(dataRng.Rows.Count).Value = dataRng.Value '<--| write corresponding calculated values
            End With
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @Chrisftw, did you get through it?